# Is there a function in Mathematica that computes the number of solutions to polynomial systems?

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

Given a system of polynomial equations in $\mathbb{C}$-coefficients, is there a tool in Mathematica that computes the number of solutions to this system, counted with multiplicity?  (We may assume that the algebraic variety defined by the system is zero-dimensional.)

Equivalently, assuming we are given an ideal $I\subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and it is known that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ is a finite dimensional linear space over $\mathbb{C}$. Is there is a tool in Mathematica that computes the complex dimension of the quotient space?

This can be done by Maple using the NumberOfSolutions function in the PolynomialIdeals package, but I am trying to learn how to do it in Mathematica. It might be somewhere in the GroebnerBasis package, but I can't seem to find it in the online manual.

Thanks a lot!

Here is a concrete example:

If we are given two polynomials `x^2-y, y^3+y+1`, then the answer should be 6, because the system of equations $x^2-y=0, y^3+y+1=0$ has 6 solutions when counted with multiplicity.

I believe the algorithm needs to somehow compute the Groebner basis of the given ideal, but I am not familiar with the details of the algorithms and couldn't figure out how to use the Groebner package for it.

Thanks again!

Comment: A concrete example always helps.

Comment: NSolve can be used with a certain Method setting.

Comment: Have you tried `CountRoots`?  If you have why doesn't it help?  Perhaps also `RootIntervals` could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments!  I need to find the exact number of solutions to a system, not numerical approximations, so perhaps NSolve doesn't work for this purpose.  This question is equivalent to the computation of the dimension of a certain quotient space, and there are known algorithms for it.  I am just trying to see if there is an easy way to use it in Mathematica.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nasser Thanks a lot for the comment!  I have added a concrete example to it.  Basically, I am looking for the equivalent tool of this function from Maple: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=PolynomialIdeals%2FNumberOfSolutions

Comment: Did you see GroebnerBasis[{x^2 - y, y^3 + y + 1}, {y}] or Eliminate[{x^2 - y == 0, y^3 + y + 1 == 0}, {y}]?

Comment: Please edit the post to plut the example system in copy-pastable format (Mathematica `InputForm` works well for this). It is the expectation for a minimal working example in this forum, and saves people from retyping or having to check comments or responses to find such code.

Comment: You might want to add an example in your question for others to use to compare with, from the Maple command you linked to which gives $\infty$. Here it is `restart;
p1 := x^2 - y + x^9; p2 := y^8 + y + 1 + x^4 + 2*y*x;
PolynomialIdeals:-NumberOfSolutions([p1,p2],'plex'(x,y))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is code I cribbed from the `NSolve` method based on computing an eigensystem from a Groebner basis.

```
borderMonomials[basis_, pvars_, order_] := Module[
  {polys, heads},
  polys = 
   First[GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[basis, pvars, 
     Sort -> False, MonomialOrder -> order, 
     CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions]];
  Quiet[heads = Map[First, polys] /.
     HoldPattern[First[{}]] :> Sequence[]];
  Map[First, heads]]

headsTable[elist_List, maxlist_, nvars_Integer] /; 
  Length[elist] == nvars :=
 Module[{jj, indices, iterators},
  indices = Array[jj, {nvars}];
  iterators = Table[{indices[[j]], 0, maxlist[[j]] - 1}, {j, nvars}];
  Flatten[Table[indices, Evaluate[Apply[Sequence, iterators]]], 
   nvars - 1]]

getRoofTuples[elist_, height_] := 
 Module[{len = Length[elist], expvec, expvecs, tt, rest}, 
  expvecs = tt[];
  Do[expvec = elist[[jj]];
   If[expvec[[height]] =!= 
      0 && (height === 1 || Max[Take[expvec, height - 1]] === 0),
    expvecs = tt[expvec, expvecs]], {jj, len}];
  expvecs = Apply[List, Flatten[expvecs, Infinity, tt]];
  rest = Complement[elist, expvecs];
  expvecs = Map[Drop[#, height - 1] &, expvecs];
  {expvecs, rest}]

isUnder[t1_, t2_] := Apply[And, Thread[t1 <= t2]]

hitRoof[tup_, roofs_] := 
 Catch[Module[{jj, len = Length[roofs]}, 
   For[jj = 1, jj <= len, jj++, 
    If[isUnder[roofs[[jj]], tup], Throw[True, "hR"]]];
   False], "hR"]

headsTable[elist_List, maxes_, nvars_Integer] := 
 Module[{tuples, ntups, tuple, ntup, mixedexpons, tt, roofs}, 
  mixedexpons = 
   Select[elist, (Max[Apply[Sequence, #]] != Apply[Plus, #]) &];
  tuples = Table[{j}, {j, 0, maxes[[nvars]] - 1}];
  Do[{roofs, mixedexpons} = getRoofTuples[mixedexpons, jj];
   ntups = tt[];
   Do[tuple = tuples[[kk]];
    ntups = tt[Prepend[tuple, 0], ntups];
    Do[ntup = Prepend[tuple, mm];
     If[hitRoof[ntup, roofs], Break[], ntups = tt[ntup, ntups]];
     , {mm, maxes[[jj]] - 1}]
    , {kk, Length[tuples]}];
   tuples = Flatten[ntups, Infinity, tt], {jj, nvars - 1, 1, -1}];
  Sort[Apply[List, tuples]]]

CountSolutions[polys_, vars_] := Module[
  {gb, elist, maxexpons, headmonoms},
  gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, 
    CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions, 
    MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];
  elist = borderMonomials[gb, vars, DegreeReverseLexicographic];
  maxexpons = Map[Max, Transpose[elist]];
  headmonoms = headsTable[elist, maxexpons, Length[vars]];
  Length[headmonoms]
  ]
```

Here is the example from the post.

```
polys = {x^2 - y, y^3 + y + 1};
vars = Variables[polys];
CountSolutions[polys, vars]

(* Out[142]= 6 *)
```

Here is a more complicated example.

```
polys = {x^3 + 5*x*z - 2*x*y - y^2 + z^3 - 3*y^2*z, 
   y^3 + x^2*y + -7*x*y*2 + 3*x^2 - 5*x*y - 1, 
   x*z^2 + 4*x*y*z + y^2*z - 2*z + x^2*y*z - 11};
vars = Variables[polys];
CountSolutions[polys, vars]

(* Out[155]= 33 *)
```

When I get a chance I'll prepare and submit this to the Wolfram Function Repository.

Comment: fyi, using the Maple command the OP linked above in the comment, it gives different answer for  one same input test I did. Here is an example. `polys=={x^2-y+x^9;y^8+y+1+x^4+2*y*x}; vars=Variables[polys]; CountSolutions[polys,vars]` gives `6` but Maple gives $\infty$ for same polynomials. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWUse.png)

Comment: Thaks for that example @Nasser. Yes, infinity is correct. I should have noted that my code explicitly expects/works on systems with finitely many solutions (this was stipulated in the original post). It is not hard to adjust to be more general and indeed `NSolve` code does have the necessary checks in place.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code!  It seems that Maple and your code give different answers for the following system: `polys = {a^5 + 30*a^3*b + 40*a^2*c + 89*ab^2 + 88*bc, 
  a^6 + 55*a^4*b + 80*a^3*c + 439*a^2*b^2 + 688*abc + 225*b^3 + 
   160*c^2, 
  a^7 + 91*a^5*b + 140*a^4*c + 1519*a^3*b^2 + 2968*a^2*bc + 
   3429*ab^3 + 1120*a*c^2 + 3708*b^2*c}`  Your code gives 146 but Maple gives 35.  Sorry for this complicated example, it is actually produced by some other computations and for this example, we do know that the answer is 35.  Maybe there is just some minor bug.  Thanks again!

Comment: @BoyuZhang I get 35 from Daniel's code if I put a space in between the letters in `ab`, `abc`, etc.

Comment: Daniel, I don't know if you want your WFR function to handle the following, but it gives and error and then the correct answer: `CountSolutions[{x^3 + Sqrt[y^4] - 1, x^2 + y^2 - 1}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 I might try to handle the error better. But getting an accurate count for such input involves finding all "solutions" and discarding parasites. And there is also an issue with multiplicity. `NSolve` gives 8 solutions, counting multiplicity,  for this example, whereas `CountSolutions` claims only 6.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, I see, thank you very much!